# java: load class at jvm startup with default params

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, startup

i'd like to print a message in the console as soon as jvm starts.
is it possible in java to provide a jar that when placed on the classpath will make jvm load some class at startup? and all that without using any additional command line options but just a standard java -cp invocation?

Comment: *is it possible in java to provide a jar that when placed on the classpath will make jvm load some class at startup?* Yes. *and all that without using any additional command line options but just a standard java -cp invocation?* No. `-Xbootclasspath` or maybe yes - take a look at [`DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: `DriverManager`, or any service provider based facility in general, will only load the implementations when being queried and since there is no guaranty that an application uses `DriverManager`, there is no guaranty that the drivers will be loaded at all, but even when being used, it doesn’t have to be at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Class, which should be load *as soon as possible*, when JVM starts up, if presented in classpath:

```
public final class Singleton {
    public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    private Singleton() {
         System.out.println("Startup");
    }
}
```

Otherwise as mentioned [-Xbootclasspath/p](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1018570) or [-javaagent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).